# Finding the sum of all primes under 2 million

Tags: c

I just wanted to know why my code doesn't give the right answer.
I've tried it with [Euler 7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7) and it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int prime = 1;
    int number = 3;
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (number <= 2000000)
    {
        counter = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < (sqrt(number) + 1); i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            printf("Number: %d Prime: %d\n", number, prime);
            prime++;
            sum = sum + number;
        }
        number++;
    }
    printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the program?

Comment: Umm, so does it work (*"tried it with Euler 7 and it works fine"*) or not (*"doesn't give the right answer"*)? And if it doesn't work, what result were you expecting and what result did you get?

Comment: Why are you checking every even number for prime, except 2, the only even number which *is* prime? Furthermore, having found one divisor, which do you plough through the rest?

Comment: ..and also, is `sum` a large enough type to hold the actual sum?

Comment: @WeatherVane : you are right. It is an overflow of `sum`,which should be typed as `unsigned long int` for instance.

Comment: @NobodyNada 1179908152

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue 1

The sum of all primes below 2000000 is 142913828922 (~1.4*10^11 ).

The maximum number that fits into an 32bit `int` is 2147483647 = 2^31-1 (~2.1*10^9).

So you are getting an integer overflow.

#### Fix 1

```
unsigned long long sum = 0;
```

and

```
printf("The sum is: %lld\n", sum);
```

should give the expected result.

#### Issue 2

2 is also a prime, but you are not counting it.

#### Fix 2

A quick hack would be to initialize `sum` with 2.

Answer (score 0):

2 is also a prime number. So, you can initialize `sum = 2` (according @sergej).

In

```
if (number % i == 0)
{
      counter++;
      break;
 }
```

You should use a `break` for reducing extra iteration because `if (number % i == 0)` is `true` then counter value is increase and it will be 1 and also perfectly work.

And you should use `unsigned long long int sum = 0` because for 2 million, `sum`  is much higher from `2^31-1` (`if you use int`).

And you display your sum value by `printf("%lld", sum)`

Comment: `int number = 2` is not enough, the sum remains wrong.

Comment: @sergej How? can you explain

How sum remains wrong? If number start from 2, it's will be a prime number and add with sum

Comment: `2 % 2 == 0` although 2 is a prime number

Comment: I would start with 3 and init the sum with 2.

Comment: I also according to you